# WPF-combobox selection changed showes last item selected instead of the current one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, selectionchanged

this is my combo box(xaml code) :

```
 <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged" Name="ComboBox1" SelectedIndex="1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="240" Width="135" Height="24">
        <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Red" Name="Red">Red</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Blue" Name="Blue">Blue</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Yellow" Name="Yellow">Yellow</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Pink" Name="Pink">Pink</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Foreground="Green" Name="Green">Green</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

and this is my c# code :

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox1.Text != "")
        {
            var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
            var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(ComboBox1.Text);
            rect.Fill = brush;
        }
    }
```

I have a rectangle that I want to fill in the color chosen in the combo box, I also want the default color on the combo box to be blue, both however don't really work for me. The text on the combo box is in fact blue by default but I think the item itself isn't selected because it doesn't recognize it and tells me my combo box string is empty by default. Furthermore, my rectangle's colors change in a delay, if I choose red first-nothing is going to happen and then if I choose green second it's gonna show red and it keeps going in that delay.

Does anyone know why? and how to solve it? I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: 2021 here, same issue ;(

Answer (score 2):

At the end I managed to solve this by changing the SelectionChanged event with the DropDownClosed event.